# A static positive charge in a uniform magnetic field watching by an observer moving at a constant speed

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, charge

[image: Image.1]

As the picture above, there is a uniform magnetic field from back to front. Put a positive charge in (x,y). Then there is an observer moving along the y-axis at a constant speed(v). Does it seem that the positive charge influenced by the Lorentz force(F=qvB) for the observer?

Comment: Search about electromagnetic forces!

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/498701/thought-experiment-and-possible-contradiction-between-electromagnetism-and-speci

Answer (score 0):

There is no force in the frame of reference of your diagram. There is therefore no force on the charge in the moving frame of reference.

Whilst force is not a relativistic invariant, it is transformed by multiplicative factors. So a force of zero in one frame of reference cannot become non-zero in another.

The way that works here is the B-field must also be transformed in the moving frame (e.g. [see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity)). The transformation results in a different B-field $\vec{B}' =\gamma \vec{B}$, where $\gamma$ is the usual Lorentz factor and an electric field, where $\vec{E}' = -\vec{v}\times \vec{B}'$, leaving the total force on the charge equal to zero according to the moving observer.